# How to extract a value from the request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

GET https://test.dnrhosted.com/profile/user?userid=66

I need this value 66 to pass across the script.

Anyone ,kindly tell me how to extract this value in jmeter..

[image: refer the screen for more info]

Comment: Should I use any Pre-Processor or Post -Processor,kindly help me

Answer (score 1):

This is not a [Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), it is an [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL)

You can extract the value as follows:

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which has or is redirected to this URL
2. Configure it as follows:

   [image]
3. That's it, you should be able to access the extracted value as `${userid}` where required:

   [image]

More information:

- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Hi Dmitri T, thanks for the reply.I did a mistake,kindly help me